# Does the avg of two endpoint's inst rate of change and the avg ROC of the interval on a parabola use the same line that touches/intercepts the graph?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials

[image: This is the idea I had in my mind]The average of two endpoint's instantaneous rates of change and the average rate of change of the interval on a parabola both result in the same answer, but do they get their answer from the same line that touches/intercepts the graph, or do they get their answer from different lines (secant, tangent, etc.) that touch/intercept the graph, and because the two lines are always parallel to each other, they result in the same answer? Endpoints as in the endpoints of the interval in the parabola.

Comment: Oops, seemed I misunderstood the question. They are the same line.

Comment: Can you explain why or provide hints as to why they are the same line?

Comment: Well both secant lines pass through the same two points

Comment: Do the secant lines overlap or are they parallel?

Comment: If they're the same line that means they are the same line. Different lines could have the same slope but pass through different points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The average of the iroc lines is not a line, but simply a slope number.

Comment: Yes, when I average the tangent lines, do they always become a secant line that overlaps the secant line made by aroc?

Comment: The slope of those lines are the instantaneous rates of change at the points they touch, and the average of the endpoint's of an interval's instantaneous rates of change and the average rate of change of the interval on a parabola both result in the same answer. So I wanted to ask if the average of the slope (forgot to include this) of those two tangent lines will make a secant line that overlaps the one made my aroc in any parabola.

Comment: Oh lol sorry. Thank you for the help.